# Firefox. Можно ли сделать так, чтобы событие mousemove не срабатывало при движении мыши, не отключая само событие?

Tags: firefox, события

Событие должно генерироваться программно Java-скриптом.

Есть событие `mousemove`, установленное на `document` чужой библиотекой, которая отслеживает движение мыши. Мой скрипт генерирует это событие, при необходимости.

Иногда, при просмотре станицы невольно попадаю на нее мышью, что рушит весь процесс - по мнению библиотеки, на странице оказываются сразу "две мыши".

Подразумеваю, что это возможно только перехватом `WinAPI`, что не подходит, а вдруг есть простое решение, учитывая гибкость настроек `Firefox`? Например, блокировка страницы от внешнего воздействия.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предлагаю накрыть всю страницу оверлеем, который на нужные события будет далать return false:

```js
document.onmousemove = function() {
  alert();
}
```

```html
<div style="position:fixed;left:0;top:0;right:0;bottom:0" onmousemove="event.stopPropagation()"></div>
```

Comment: Попробовал со своими собиями - работает. Вообще, нужно для работы с Вебзиором. Его обмануть не получается. Еще раз пересмотрел код Вебвизора, события вешаются на document, но каким образом он ловит их при stopPropagation() ?

Comment: @Дмитрий: возможно, он раньше вашего stopPropagation ловит event (например, если он capturing, а вы bubbling) - http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-flow Если никак не удается оказаться первому - можно загрузить нужную страницу в фрейм, а оверлей оставить в "родительской" странице.